# Lua: Install a rock using luarocks from a locally installed rock (or from a .zip/.tar.gz)

Tags: lua, luarocks

I hunted around but I couldn't determine if this is possible.

Basically, http://luarocks.org is down, and I already have a copy of luafilesystem installed on another machine locally here.  With Ruby, it's possible to cross install ruby gems using the 'gem' command locally.  I'm wondering if the same is possible with rocks and luarocks.

Is there any way to 'cross-install' a rock (for instance, luafilesystem), by using another local installation of that rock?

Something like:

`luarocks install //10.0.1.123/machine/path/to/luafilesystem/on/other/machine`

is what I'd like to be able to do.

UPDATE: I'd even be happy with how to install a rock from the .tar.gz or .zip, for instance, if I downloaded one of the images from [this location](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luafilesystem/luafilesystem/luafilesystem-1.4.2) (in the case of LuaFileSystem).

In which case, the 'source' for the install would / could be local to the machine, rather than remote (and wouldn't necessarily already be installed as a rock).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LuaRocks has a `pack` subcommand that will create a binary rock (a zip file containing all files for an installed module). You can use that binary rock to install the same module on another computer, given that the architecture matches.

E.g.

```
luarocks pack luafilesystem
```

produces `luafilesystem-1.6.2-2.linux-x86_64.rock` on my machine, and

```
luarocks install luafilesystem-1.6.2-2.linux-x86_64.rock
```

will reinstall `luafilesystem` with no internet connection necessary.

Answer (score 27):

If you have the source zip, you can unpack it and point luarocks to the the rockspec file.  Here is how I installed 'busted' from source.

```
git clone https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted.git
luarocks install busted/busted-1.3-1.rockspec
```

Or install it directly from source

```
cd busted
luarocks make
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert Wahler - You have answered my "UPDATE:" to the question, which is quite helpful.  I was hoping to also get an answer for my original question too (which is to install a rock from one that's already installed--but perhaps that's not possible). In any case, you get an upvote from me!

Comment: I don't know of an automatic way to do what you ask since on install, the code and bin wrappers can end up in different locations. For both gems and rocks, I create a vendor folder that is embedded in each project so deployments don't depend on 3dparty hosted services like rubygems.org or luarocks.org.

Answer (score 12):

If Someone want an installation from the local source rock.

Just do this:

```
cd /path/to/source-rock
luarocks make source-rock.rockspec
```

**NOTE:**

Use **`make`** instead of `install`. The reason is [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-08/msg00836.html) (quoted below).

> > LuaRocks offers this:
> >
> > `make`    Compile package in current directory using a rockspec.
> >
> > `install` Install a rock.
> >
> > However, `install` does not utilize the present make.  It tries
> >     to download and recompile the same package from the server instead
> >     of the one I customized locally.
> >
> > Any way round this?
>
> The `make` command will actually build and install your customized
>   rockspec. The poor naming choice causes confusion every now and then,
>   I know.