# Installing Luarocks `cutorch` and `cunn`

Tags: lua, torch

### Problem

I cannot install specific Luarocks.
I want to determine key points in 3D hand scans using a CNN. Therefore, I want to get [V2V-PoseNet](https://github.com/mks0601/V2V-PoseNet_RELEASE) running. However, I run into a problem and the researcher [suggested](https://github.com/mks0601/V2V-PoseNet_RELEASE/issues/12) me to try:

```
$luarocks install cutorch
$luarocks install cunn
```

Unfortunately, I get the error that I have no writing permissions. When executing with `sudo`, I get:

```
Error: No results matching query were found.
```

### What I've tried

I have installed Torch correctly (`th` works) and I did a clean install of Luarocks:

```
$th
  ______             __   |  Torch7 / Debian 
 /_  __/__  ________/ /   |  Scientific computing for Lua. 
  / / / _ \/ __/ __/ _ \  |  Type ? for help 
 /_/  \___/_/  \__/_//_/  |  https://github.com/torch 
                          |  http://torch.ch 
th>^C^C

$sudo apt-get install luarocks
```

and then try to install the rocks:

```
$sudo luarocks install cutorch
$sudo luarocks install cunn
```

Without the sudo command, it is not working. The installation commands above return both `Error: No results matching query were found`. Someone with a similar problem was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253165/lua-install-a-rock-using-luarocks-from-a-locally-installed-rock-or-from-a-zip) to install the rock manually. If I manually download the [cutorch-master](https://github.com/torch/cutorch), start a terminal from the folder /rocks and run

```
$luarocks install cutorch-1.0-0.rockspec
```

I get the error that my user 'does not have write permissions in /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks'. When I try to install with `sudo`, I get `Missing dependencies for cutorch 1.0-0: torch >= 7.0 (not installed)`. I tried to modify .bashrc, but that was not successful, although I was able to repair that in the mean time.

By the way, Lua itself is installed:

```
$lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

### Installation

I am running this from Ubuntu 18.04.

### My question

How to install `cutorch` and `cunn` with Luarocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I set up Ubuntu 18.04 again and installed Torch according to the [documentation](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_).

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
./install.sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, I installed [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.2/Prod2/local_installers/cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux) and ran it:

```
sudo sh cuda_9.2.148_396.37_linux.run
```

After I intalled [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.2.1/prod/9.2_20180806/cudnn-9.2-linux-x64-v7.2.1.38), I was able to run the commands above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing a `cunn` rock uploaded to the luarocks server: https://luarocks.org/search?q=cunn

Could you ask the author of the package to upload it to the public server?